# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application.

I am trying to convert a string in application.properties file to a Map in a DTO.

My application.properties looks like this:

```
...
com.myapp.someMap={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
```

DTO.java

```
class MyDTO {

...
@Value("#{${com.myapp.someMap}}")
Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();

}
```

I get this error when the Application tries to start

```
Failed to bind properties under 'com.myapp.someMap' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>:


    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]
```

Comment: Can you show us how you use the `MyDTO` class? I created a new Spring Boot project and copied your code and it works fine for me. So I guess something is different about the way you construct or use `MyDTO`.

Comment: @时间只会一直走 You do realize that Hexy is using the top voted answer on that question right?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your repo where this is working?